# Read folder containing CSV file and rbind them with a FASTER APPROACH

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse

Hi guys im trying  to load alot of .CSV file from a folder called Daily -DWReport
and also bind row them and its freaking slow
is there a better way to import all these files at once and rbind them

here is the current script running

```r
Warehouse_report <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Guest 1/Desktop/Daily -DWReport", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
Warehouse <- sapply(Warehouse_report, read_csv, simplify=FALSE) %>%   
  bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

Comment: Your present method is the most straight-forward and typically among the fastest. If you're having performance issues with this code, then it is likely with `readr::read_csv`, and perhaps due to very large files. If that's the case, there are alternatives, some claim to be faster: `data.table::fwrite` and `vroom::vroom` come to mind, there may be others.

Comment: Another option (depending on the size and your intended use for looking at the data) is to put the data into a database of sources, whether a "trim" database like SQLite or DuckDB, or a bigger one like postgres. If you go this route, there are ways to read the data into the database that are much faster if you bypass R and add it direct. However, this (database) path really only makes sense if you're planning on analyzing a subset of the data at a time; loading all files into a DB and then querying all data into R is not going to solve your problem.